# Cannot access wsl web app from windows after installing docker

Tags: windows, docker, ip-address, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I had no issues with accessing my apps running in Ubuntu through WSL from windows until I installed docker and did a reboot.

I checked my hosts configuration file and it looked something like the following:

```
# Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Microsoft Corp.
#
# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
#
# This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each
# entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should
# be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
# The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one
# space.
#
# Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
# lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
#
# For example:
#
#      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
#       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host

# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#       127.0.0.1       localhost
#       ::1             localhost
# Added by Docker Desktop
192.168.1.244 host.docker.internal
192.168.1.244 gateway.docker.internal
# To allow the same kube context to work on the host and the container:
127.0.0.1 kubernetes.docker.internal
# End of section
```

I commented out the second to last line

```
# 127.0.0.1 kubernetes.docker.internal
```

and flushed my dns using

```
ipconfig /flushdns
```

but still if I try to access my node app running on port 3001 in wsl my browser gives the "Can't reach this page message"

This isn't an issue with node or my app because I am able to successfully curl my app from the ubuntu terminal

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix the issue by simply adding the ip address for wsl to my hosts file above the docker declaration:

```
<ip address of wsl> localhost
```